# Using multiple models as User in Keystone.js

Tags: keystonejs

I'm using Keystone.js to develop a relatively simple system. But, I have 3 different types of user. They may have access to different sections and resources, they will have a different UI and they will also have different properties. I need them to appear separated in the Admin UI. I also want to use Keystone sessions for the users.

Which would be the best approach to solve this? I would like to register 3 different models as Keystone's User Model, but I'm not sure if it is possible. I've been researching without success.

I'd preferably avoid using the same model for the 3, but if it's the best way, I'm not closed to it.

Comment: The use case you are describing should be handled by different user roles & permissions (rather than different User models), but this isn't a current built-in feature for Keystone 4. There are several approaches to implement roles depending on your requirements, so "best approach" is going to be elusive without more detail. See https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/803 and linked issues for some past discussion on possible approaches.

Comment: Thank you, Stennie! I'm building a site where people from 2 different companies are going to enter to different sections and people from none of the companies can create their own account and enter to a different section. The main problem is that the 3 different types of users have a lot of different properties between them. I was thinking, is it possible to inherit from User model, so, I'll still able to use keystone.session with different models?